# jQuery Gantt plugin - Divider showing current week

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, gantt-chart

I'm trying to use the jQuery plugin for Gantt charts. How do I get a divider sort of line showing the current week, and perhaps highlight what has been completed and what is yet to be completed in different colors?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what plugin you are using here?

In any case, to be able to delineate weeks with a lines, zoomable timeline, highlight weekends and holidays, include progress information in the task bar and a whole bunch of other features, you should consider the [RadiantQ jQuery Gantt Package](http://radiantq.com/products/jquery-gantt-package/jquery-gantt-package-features/).